# DocuSign : Is it possible to edit viewed documents using API

Tags: docusignapi

Could you please go through below scenario and provide a solution for us?

In our document we have agreement start date field. Initially when document is loaded, this field is populated from our database. We want to change this date according to the user sign this document.

That is, user may view the document but sign after 2 or 3 months. On similar cases we want to change the agreement date to new date using API.

Plese provide a solution.

Comment: Happy Coding. SO 
is about fixing _your_ Code - not implementing your ideas. 
Please go over [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and 
[on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) again and if you have questions provide 
your code as [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).If you encounter errors, copy and paste
the error message verbatim ( word for word) into your question. Avoid using screenshots unless you 
need to convey layout errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot alter anything in the document (including field values) if Signer has completed the signing ceremony. Since you need an agreement date when Signer is signing the document, I would suggest to use [DS Date Signed Tabs](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipientTabs/create/#/definitions/dateSigned). DateSigned tab will only be populated when signer completes the Signing ceremony and you can pull this date via API in your Database to save it in your system.